# I'm getting syntax error when trying to send password in form

Tags: php

I'm very new at php. I get these errors when I write these codes.

[image: the code]
[image: the error]

Comment: please add the actual code rather than a screenshot of the code. The problem is that you do not check for the existence of the querystring parameter `islem` before trying to use it in logic operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if islem was passed in before trying to access it

```
if (isset($_POST['islem']) {
 // your code here
}
```

Otherwise you won't be able to load the page up initially in order to submit the form.  Also notice that I used _POST here, this is because you used the POST method in your form.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method POST in the form and getting the variables with GET

```
Either Try method : GET or try $_POST["islem"];
```